# How do I read data from cache using JavaAPI after I put it through jdbc?

Tags: sql, ignite

For instance, I've created table using next DDL-query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Person 
(id int PRIMARY KEY, city_id int, name varchar, company varchar, age int)
  WITH "template=partitioned, value_type=MyPerson";
```

Now i'm going to have it read from cache as MyPerson object. How do I do that? Do I need also to define MyPerson class? What if it would contain some (or totally) other fields that than Person table has?

Comment: Can you please add a tag for the SQL dialect you're using? E.g. MySQL or SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

You can either create the `MyPerson` class or use `withKeepBinary` flag and `BinaryObject` API. See here for more details: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/binary-marshaller#binaryobject-cache-api

If you use the latter, you will have all the fields available. If you deserialize into a class instance, you will of course only have fields that are available in the class. Anything else would be ignored. Fields that exist in class but not in cache will be initialized with default values (nulls and zeros).

Comment: Ok, but what's the purpose of VALUE_TYPE option then, if I actually don't have value_type class defined at the moment I've created a table? I suppose ignite implicitly create valuetype class to store data in kv store, but then why do I need to create another valuetype class only to read data from cache?

Comment: Ignite doesn't create classes or instances of these classes. It stores everything in binary format and works with binary objects only. If you never deserialize, `VALUE_TYPE` is just the name that identifies the type. If you do deserialize, full class name of your class has to be the same as `VALUE_TYPE`.

Comment: @aryndin I've prepared a special project on GitHub that shows how to mix and match SQL with key-value APIs in Ignite. It covers your case: https://github.com/dmagda/ignite_world_demo

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to do. Skim through this GitHub project that shows how to blend SQL and key-value APIs together. It covers your scenario:
https://github.com/dmagda/ignite_world_demo